# Encoding in a list of dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, python-2.x

I have a list `mylist` of dict with an encoding problem:

```
>>print mylist
[{u'param1': u'foo',u'param2': u'Special char \xe9'}, ...]

>>for item in mylist:
>>    print item
{u'param1': u'foo',u'param2': u'Special char \xe9'}
...

>>for item in input:
>>    for i in item:
>>        print 'Key: %s Value: %s' % (i, item[i])
Key: param1
Value: foo
Key: param2
Value: Special char é
```

(`\xe9` is `é`)

How can I modify the encoding to have directly:

```
>>print mylist
[{param1: 'foo',param2: 'Special char é'}, ...]
```

Comment: You can't, because that is just the result of calling `__repr__` on the members of the list; but more to the point, you **don't need to**, since there is absolutely no reason to rely on this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is already encoded the correct way. If you however `print` a dictionary, it calls `repr(..)` on the keys and values and then escape encoding is used. If you however `print(..)` a specific value, it will show it as you want, since the `str(..)` is used. The `\xe9` is only for programmers convenience such that you can easily copy the output and feed it for instance to a program:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mylist = [{u'param1': u'foo',u'param2': u'Special char \xe9'}]
>>> print(mylist[0]['param2'])
Special char é
```